# Regular expression to English

Tags: regex

Given a regular expression, is there a library or webservice which will give the human/non-programmer an English description?

For example, `.+`  =>  one or more characters

Comment: Consider to move to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know about a website, but [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) will do that for you.

[image]

Comment: is it  only for purchase no free version is available ?

Comment: That's correct, but it's *so* worth it. And I'm not affiliated with JGSoft in any way.

Comment: Surely doable for Free!!

Even if advertising supported!!

Comment: @WillHancock: You're right. I've added another answer.

Comment: This is the first software product I ever paid for. And I don't regret it.

Comment: Expresso is free and it does the same. See https://ultrapico.com/expresso.htm

Answer (score 77):

There is an excellent site called http://regex101.com that does exactly that, as well. It also provides access to different regex engines, allows you to save and debug your regexes and test strings...very nice.

[image: regex101 screenshot]

Comment: Perfect site. Loved the unit tests it has...

Comment: This site is good, but the explanation cannot be copied (to put in source, for example).

Answer (score 10):

I'm a big fan of [RegExr](http://regexr.com). Similar to regex101, but has more features and a nicer interface in my opinion.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I was looking for something like this myself a few minutes ago, so here is the solution I found with a quick Google search.

http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws

The explanation is a little terse, but worked well enough for my needs.
Here in a link to a screenshot (not enough reputation to post images).
[image]
[Screenshot of a simple regex example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYrW7.png)

I tried Tim Peitzcker's suggested regex101.com, but liked the simple format of this site better.

Answer (score 2):

Regex Coach can do this, though it is a desktop app rather than something callable http://weitz.de/regex-coach/